# Android Show Blob Images in listview when scroll.

Tags: android, image, listview

Hi I want to show the images in listview when user scroll the list. 
I retrieved the image from database(blob) not from web service.
**for example**
I have an 40 items in the list view and in my mobile screen 10 item is visible. when i scroll the list it load the next images. i don't want to load the 40 images concurrently.
list will show images between Fisrt Visible Position and Last Visible Position.

- Like in a twitter app  the images first blank when user scroll then it load in the listview

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you finding is called Lazy Loading Adapter, [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) will work as you want check this link, this loads images in lazy manner.